# Can't find usb_driver folder in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

Tried every solution I've found on here but to no avail.

I'm trying to root my phone, and the instructions say to find the google usb_driver folder in the Android SDK.

I installed it using the SDK manager but the folder isn't anywhere on my pc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your sdk manager and make sure you have downloaded the package named **Google USB Driver**: 
[image]

If you have done this then you can find the folder in the following directory:
For my computer:
*C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver*